# How can I align the contact center?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this page:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=25

I want to align elements (text + map + contact form)

I use a plugin for Wordpress to create this form.
The plugin is called CformBuilder

This is code for my page:

```
    <div class="parentVerticalCenter">
    <div class="childVerticalCenter">


  <div class="row sss">

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12" style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
[Contact_Form_Builder id="10"]
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?
I tried several variations but unfortunately we did

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could change bootstrap grid class for something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
```

Learn more about offset here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: are you sure it is aligned with the center well for all resolutions?My impression is that it is not properly aligned

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this...

```
after install plugin you can see in admin in tools goto form builder

and see the standard css enable:

please disable and put your custom css
```

like textalign:center what ever align you want

The FormBuilder comes with a standard CSS formatting file which can be used in the event that your template does not have support for the FormBuilder fields. By default, use of this standard CSS is enabled, but in the event that you wish to use custom CSS, or a template which already supports the FormBuilder system, you may disable the built-in CSS formatting by selecting your preference below.